# Non-retina images on the bottom of the Approve tag wiki edits help page

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

There are two non-retina images on the bottom of [the Approve tag wiki edits help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits):

[image: non-retina images on the bottom of the help page]

They could easily be replaced with a retina picture or with the badge container span itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images updated to hi-DPI versions.

Thanks for reporting.

Comment: Not really, they are [oversized now.](http://i.imgur.com/eudnMg8.png)

Comment: Fixed that now.

Comment: Is there a technical reason that images have to be used here, instead of actual badges? If you used the actual badge thingadongdongs, then they'd be properly "localized" for all the different sites.

Comment: @CodyGray - the help pages are just posts, like questions and answers. We don't have a "badge thingadondong" for badges (like we do for tags). Help pages can also be overridden per site, which was done for localization reasons.

Comment: I *think* they now look blurry on non-retina screens. Not sure though. But since they're just like posts, I suppose nothing can be done about it?

Comment: Yeah, they look blurrier on my non-high DPI screen, @Stijn. I was just referring to the HTML markup you use to render badges elsewhere, but I guess that answers my question. If they're just posts, then there's no way to embed that into posts.