# Markdown syntax for badges in posts

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges, markdown

[My bug report](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356391/non-retina-images-on-the-bottom-of-the-approve-tag-wiki-edits-help-page) showed the need of a markdown that can be used in posts to show a badge, just like a tag markup (`[tag:foo]`).

While I agree that the posts on SO won't have too much of a benefit from it, on Meta, this would be kind of useful. On the top of that, pages inside the Help section work like posts - just like questions and answers -, and they *would* benefit from this addition.

Comment: This is the first genuine use-case of this I've seen since registering. Changing this would've made the bug report unclear, after the fix, though...

Comment: See [Add badges to Markdown?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100306/add-badges-to-markdown)

Comment: @Cerbrus it would also be useful for Meta posts, where we currently need to manually link to a badge. The `[tag:foo]` feature is also only useful on Meta.

Comment: I actually link to tags on SO as well.

Comment: @Cerbrus In what context?

Comment: References to tags make sense on the main site in only one context: when you want to provide an entry-point to the tag wiki. Some tag wikis are of exceptional quality, and contain lots of great reference information.

Answer (score 2):

While waiting for the feature to get implemented, you can use this trick to display the badge:

- Take a screenshot of the element in the browser:

[image]

- Upload the image by dragging it to the editor.
- Use this syntax to display the badge as an image:

```
[![reactjs gold badge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mt3hO.png)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5357/reactjs)
```

Here is the example result:

[image: reactjs gold badge] - Earn at least 1000 total score for at least 200 non-community wiki answers in the [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) tag. These users can single-handedly mark [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) questions as duplicates and reopen them as needed.

Comment: This does "work", but it looks really bad. I would not recommend doing this. And I can't imagine a valid use-case, outside of perhaps discussing tag badges themselves on Meta sites.